# ginger space explorer

Tags: story-identification

I'm searching for the name of a novel and the name of its author. I'm pretty sure it is pre-1975 and probably from the 50's.

A ginger space explorer for some industrial complex in some space empire (crash)lands on an undiscovered, inhabited planet. Life on the planet is idyllic (a bit Pacific-island-like). He is nursed back to health and gradually falls in love with the people of the planet (and a girl). He knows what will happen to the planet when it is rediscovered by another explorer, and makes a scenario for the people to follow in this event (using all his knowledge of galactic law).
Rediscovery happens after his death, and his descendants follow the scenario to get recognition and admission as a self-governing entity (after organising elections). And the self-government counters greedy exploiters (who are already transforming the planet into a giant holiday resort) by voting a yearly property tax of several times the nominal worth of the buildings, also due by all inhabitants of the planet who live in straw huts (worth almost nothing).

With many thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/171276/stranded-spaceman-prepares-a-plan-to-defend-pristine-planet-against-land-grab-an (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 9):

This is ["Monument"](http://www.baenebooks.com/chapters/1416520724/1416520724___2.htm) by Lloyd Biggle Jr. (link goes to original novelette version)

[Wikipedia says:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monument_%28novel%29)

> Monument is a science fiction novel written by Lloyd Biggle, Jr. and
>   published in 1974. The subject of destructive tourism is serious, but
>   as usual with Biggle, the treatment is in a lighter vein, and at times
>   frankly humorous.
>
> Monument was based on a short story (novelette) of the same name
>   published in Analog magazine in 1961.

From the back cover:

> Lost Eden
>
> It was a world of dazzling but deadly beauty, where pleasure was man's
>   most precious birthright. In this lost colony the inhabitants had
>   forgotten the very existence of earth. Only one man remembered. He
>   foresaw the awesome consequences if this paradise were ever
>   rediscovered.

Comment: It's a wonderful novel.

Comment: There is a novel length version of this story? I must find that ... I've only read the short story which is a classic.