# Stranded spaceman prepares a plan to defend pristine planet against land-grab and exploitation

Tags: story-identification, space-colonization

A spaceship technician landed (crashed?) on a pristine planet (strong Polynesian resemblance) where a tribe of humans lives in harmony with nature, isolated from predatory capitalist humanity, colonising more and more space.

He decides to train them how to resist against expected land grab and corporate invasion. Dies before first space mission arrives, leaving detailed handwritten plan.

The whole plot is about the -- eventually successful --  resistance, run non-violent and legally-supported way.

Possible title "X's Planet" or "X's Plan" -- X being the name of the said spaceman.

Comment: "Monument" by Lloyd Biggle, Jr. First a novelette, then expanded into a novel. Were you looking for the novelette or the novel?

Comment: Biggle's "Monument" has been identified a bunch of times on this site, e.g. [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108994/short-sci-fi-story-of-plan-devised-by-marooned-spaceship-pilot-to-save-paradise).

Comment: May the loas of Matrix bless you. It was itching me for a while.
I am not sure which one I read originally, but will check both of them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the wonderful novel Monument by Lloyd Biggle.

After the natives succeed in retaining control of the planet, some of the invaders discuss how the unknown mentor saved the natives, and how it's kind of sad that he is unknown. Unbeknowst to them though, the natives have re-named the planet after him, hence the title.

http://garthright.blogspot.com/2011/01/monument-by-lloyd-biggle-jr.html

Comment: Can you tell from the question if the OP read the [short form](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55503) or the [long form](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?4567)?

Comment: I was unaware of the short form of the work.