# Redheaded scout educates backwater isolated planet of humans on how to use paperwork to avoid exploitation

Tags: story-identification, space-exploration

I recall reading a short story, novella, or novel of a crash-landed (?) redheaded scout who educates a backwater isolated planet of humans on how to use paperwork to avoid exploitation by an expanding human empire.  When empire finally came, his redheaded descendants use fees, fines, documentation, paperwork, and procedural methodology to protect the planet and its people from those who would exploit the "ignorant savages."  What is the name of this story/novel?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. Could you take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details you can remember? Every little bit helps us.

Comment: "Monument" by Lloyd Biggle, Jr. It has come up here a number of times. You can read the original novelette for free at [www.baen.com](http://www.baen.com/Chapters/1416520724/1416520724___2.htm). It was expanded into a novel which has a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monument_(novel)). Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/171276/stranded-spaceman-prepares-a-plan-to-defend-pristine-planet-against-land-grab-an?noredirect=1&lq=1 is a pretty good example.

Comment: The novelette has appeared under [these covers](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?55503) and the novel with [these covers](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?4567).

Comment: I submitted the question.  "Monument" by Lloyd Biggle, Jr. is correct.  Thanks!